# how to configure sendgrid 's from email in nodemail?

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid, nodemailer

I am using node.js 's email module nodemail and sendgrid API to send the email to the users.

Here is my code for sending a email

```
        SOURCE_EMAIL = ?????;
        var options = {
            auth: {
                api_user: sendgrid.api,
                api_key: sendgrid.key
            }
        };
        transport = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));
        transport.sendMail({from: SOURCE_EMAIL, to: email, subject: subject, html: html}, function(err,data){
});
```

my question is when I use the sendgrid API to send email, what SOURCE_MAIL i should configure to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set `SOURCE_EMAIL` to anything you want.

It's best to set it to an email you own, control, and can receive email from.

However, it's entirely up to you.